# octet_length and pg_column_size are too small for integer

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, disk-space

My postgres ID field is an integer. Just a regular integer as far as I can tell, not a bigint or smallint.

```
 \d my_table
                                      Table "public.my_table"
   Column    |            Type             |                        Modifiers                         
-------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                     | not null default nextval('tags_id_seq'::regclass)
…
```

I expect an int to be 4 bytes based on [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT)., but when I check the octet length, it says 2 bytes, and pg_column size says 3 bytes—both smaller than I'd expect. How should I interpret this?

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(avg(octet_length('id'))) as oct_length
FROM "my_table"

{"oct_length"=>"2.0000000000000000 bytes"}
```

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(avg(pg_column_size('id'))) as column_size
FROM "my_table"

{"column_size"=>"3.0000000000000000 bytes"}
```

Background: This table has some string columns that I'm thinking of converting to integers with an application-layer enum mapping to save space. But how much space would I save? I have to find out how much space each row takes up now to project how much I could save. The table is bloated, so I'm not just dividing the total size by the number of rows; I need to know how much space I can still save even after repacking. But `octet_length` and  `pg_column_size` aren't giving me consistent results and don't match what I'd expect for an integer, so how can I trust them for a string field?

Comment: You are measuring the length and the "column" size of the string literal `'id'`; I guess you meant to query `pg_column_size(id)` instead. Note that you cannot call `octet_size(id)` on an integer column (unless you cast its values to strings, which would not give you the expected result anyway).

Comment: Thank you, @mustaccio! That's simpler than I could have hoped!